# Spring bootproject running fine but giving DataSource error on Cntroller test

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I’m getting the following error to controller test i wrote:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1790) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1346) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]

the application itself is running all fine. I configured the data source (MySQL) in `application.properties`-- didn't programmatically configure a bean for it, and no problems of any kind with the `dataSource` when i run the application itself.

The dependencies are as follows:  (omitted the irrelevant ones)

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

The test class has the following configuration --

```
@WebMvcTest(UserController.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-integrationtest.properties")
public class UserControllerTest {

    @MockBean private UserService userService;
    @MockBean private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired private MockMvc mockMvc;
    ...
```

application-integrationtest.properties has all&only the following --

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
```

what am i missing??

what if i configure `DataSource` bean in the code-- where i do it? The application is running all around with no such errors. How do i define the `DataSource` for test use without any tempering with the `DataSource` of Application domain ?

any help would be appreciated.

Not too savvy with recent version-- been a while since setting up Spring boot.
Wore me out.

Comment: You shouldn't need the datasource at all when using an `@WebMvcTest`. Which means you are probably messing around with things you shouldn't making slice testing nog work. I would suspect you would only need a mock for the `UserService` not the repository.

Comment: @M.Deinum- it's doing the same thing without the repository. in fact, i put the repository there to try out whether it'd fix.

Comment: @M.Deinum any suggestions where to look --SecurityConfig, MySQL config(application.properties).. ? i configured it all pretty much the standard way. i can't think of anything else outside the above 2

Comment: Apparently your service depends on the datasource else it wouldn't ask for it. If not you have too much configuration on your `@SpringBootApplication` and the test framework cannot disable parts of the configuration. All in all there is too little information here to answer this question.